# Run .hta file by clicking button using chrome in local host

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to run a .hta file in my directory by clicking on a button my code is as:

```
$(document).on('click', '#bt0', function(){ 
  window.open('C:/Users/EliteBook/Desktop/New folder/RunExe.hta');
});
```

However it always opens a blank tab, not the file I want to open. Is the localhost restricting the file from opening? How can I run a file by clicking a button on localhost or server? I'm using chrome browser for my app.

Comment: Look in your browser's console (F12): *Not allowed to load local resource* (or in IE *Access is denied*).

Comment: Yes, the browser will be stopping you. You say you're running on localhost, yet the file path is clearly pointing to your C: drive. If you run on a legitimate server this should work - although the file will need to be downloaded before it can be opened

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are trying to load a local File, you need to use a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

When opening a Local File, the URL will use `file:///`. So for your code, you may want to try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#bt0', function(){ 
  window.open('file:///C:/Users/EliteBook/Desktop/New%20folder/RunExe.hta');
});
```

This may not work as the Browsers security may prevent this.

The `%20` is the ASCII representation of a Space character. URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus `+` sign or with `%20`.